# JButton mouse over motion listener small info frame (Tooltip)

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

I need to add a box like this to my `JButton` when the `mouseMotionListener` is active:

[image]

However, I don't know what the name of this box is in Java Swing.

Does anyone know what the declaration name is for this?

Comment: It's a tooltip - see [How to use tooltips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) for more details

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question would be best solved by reading an appropriate tutorial, like [How to Use Tool Tips](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html) and/or [How to use buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would vote for closing too, but not for the same reason: he cannot look for a tutorial as he had forgotten the name of this element x)
But it's not really a programming question, it's more about vocabulary.

Comment: @Nathan The answer is still best found through the tutorials - and I'm pretty sure 10 minutes of googling would have helped fix the vocabulary issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that your JButton name is 'button' so 
`button.setToolTipText("Your text here");` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You should be referring to a [tooltip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html).